# ASP.net Razor return image URL in JSON from upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

Below I have code from my image upload returning JSON information about the image. Near the assignment of the name parameter I am trying to return the URL of the image although it is not working. Currently the below code does not work as nothing is returned to the browser upon return. The code works fine albeit for the line to add to the Name property near the end.

How can I return the URL of the image so as to display the image URL to the user on return?

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult UploadFiles()
{
    var r = new List<UploadFilesResult>();

    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
            continue;

        string savedFileName = Url.Content(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)));
        hpf.SaveAs(GetNewPathForDupes(savedFileName));

        r.Add(new UploadFilesResult()
        {
            Name = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)),
            Length = hpf.ContentLength,
            Type = hpf.ContentType
        });
    }

    return Content("{\"name\":\"" + r[0].Name + "\",\"type\":\"" + r[0].Type + "\",\"size\":\"" + string.Format("{0} bytes", r[0].Length) + "\"}", "application/json");
}
```

**EDIT**
my Javascript to process the form in the done parameter i am trying to read the JSON but cant get it to work with the new Jsonresult:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "UploadFiles",
                autoUpload: true,
                done: function (e, data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    $('.file_name').html(json.name);
                    $('.file_type').html(json.type);
                    $('.file_size').html(json.size);
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why not use a `JsonResult`?

Comment: Why are u returning content return Json(r);

Comment: Aren't you already returning the url as the name attribute? If you switch to JsonResult as suggested by dav_i it should be easy to access in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of

```
return this.Content("{\"name\":\"" + r[0].Name + ...
```

you could simply do this:

```
return this.Json(r[0]);
```

---

When reading the JSON in your jQuery you will need to do

```
var jsonString = // from the response

var json = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

var name = json.someElement;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is definitely more manageable to dealing with the JSON data. In my Javascript 'done' function i have attempted at retrieving the data although it doesn't seem to be working. I will edit the answer.